# How to remove focus from a textbox in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a aspx page. By default, when the page loads the focus is on first textbox. I want to remove the focus to nothing. I am developing this website for a mobile device.

We have come to this nothing conclusion due to some cross browser restrictions we faced with IE.

`Page.Focus();` in the init is not working and I don't want to set up the focus to anything.

This information is all I have. Hope it is sufficient for possible resolution.

I will appreciate your feedback and time spend on this query...

Comment: I am unable to recreate this. Can you post the markup? Are you sure there isn't any relevant code-behind?

Comment: If you are "developing this website for a mobile device" then why do you care how it performs in IE. The beauty of developing for mobile sites is that you don't have to deal with IE (although Blackberry are the IE of the mobile world).

Comment: @dav_i client requirement, can't do anything. We are also targeting IE10 on Windows 8.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative can be to create a hidden control and move the focus to that control

Comment: This won't work in IE. See: http://api.jquery.com/focus/  An alternative is to create a transparent control, i.e. with opacity:0.

Comment: ...or a control positioned off the screen.

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to use jQuery why don't you do

```
$('#idOfInputWhichKeepsOnGettingFocus').blur();
```

If not, create a new first field

```
<input id="youCannotSeeMe" style="position:absolute; left:9001px;" />
```

Comment: Good point... in that case you would do `document.getElementById('id').blur()`.

Answer (score 0):

This works:
 `Page.SetFocus(this);`